# Function in $\mathbb R^{20}$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, solution-verification

I am looking at the following function $f(x)= 3+\cos(3x)-0.5\sin(5x)+0.2\cos\left(10x-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$ and I need to answer several questions.

1) What is or are the global minimizer(s)?

-I believe there are none- do you agree with my findings?

Let g(x)=$\mathbb R^{20}$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$ where g(**x**)=$f(x_1)$$f(x_2)$...$f(x_{20})$

2) Estimate how many critical points $g$ has in the cube $[0,2\pi]^{20}$.

-There are approximately 12 critical points in f so can I just take 12(20) to get the estimate of the number of critical points in $\mathbb R^{20}$?

3) Clearly there is a potential to have many (irrelevant) local minima. Can you suggest ways of handling problems like this?

-I'm not sure how to answer this part... is there a way to put restrictions on what you consider to be a local minima? Like for the function f(x) we are only looking at the interval from 0 to $2\pi$. Could we just say we want to look at local minima that are less than a certain value??

Comment: Did you set the derivative to zero and try to solve it? Note that it has period $2\pi$, so you only need to check for solutions on that interval. And since the function's continuous, and $[0, 2\pi]$ is compact, it not only has a minimum, it achieves it.